# How to run 2 functions in parallel using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, subprocess, python-multithreading

I have a job which calls start_measure function that runs a while loop to read a counter & store its value in a list as a separate process

Then I run a workload for some time in parallel

How can I run a python function start_measure() independently and stop the while loop using function call stop_measure()?

```
def run_job():
    start_measure()
    run_workload()
    stop_measure()


def start_measure():
    while 1:
        # Read the counter&  store in list


def stop_measure():
    # stop while loop & store the list in file

def run_workload():
    # do something for random time duration
```

Comment: It depends, as is often the case.  Is the "counter" you're checking being updated by the workload?  If so, perhaps you could use a `queue`, and have the workload feed the results into the `queue` to be pulled out by another thread.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [Tim Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883316/tim-roberts), you can implement a producer/consumer pattern, using a `queue`.

Here an example of an implementation based on the [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor), from the `concurrent.futures` library:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import queue
import random
import threading
import time
import logging


def get_measurements(queue_in, event):
    """Pretend retrieving measurements from somewhere and put them in a queue."""
    logger = logging.getLogger('get_measurements')

    i = -1
    while not event.is_set():
        i += 1
        message = (i, random.randint(1, 101))
        logger.info('Received measurement: %s', message)
        queue_in.put(message)

        # Add some sleep time at the end of each batch of 5 measurements to avoid a deadlock
        if (i % 5) == 4:
            time.sleep(0.1)

    logger.info('End of acquisition')


def process_measurements(queue_in, queue_out, event, max_seconds):
    """process the measurements and put the result in another queue"""

    logger = logging.getLogger('process_measurements')

    i = 0
    start_time = time.time()
    while not event.is_set() and (time.time() - start_time) < max_seconds:
        # wait for the queue to have something
        if queue_in.empty():
            continue

        # Get an element from the measurement queue and process it
        measurement = queue_in.get()
        logger.info('Process measurement: %s', measurement)
        processed_item = (measurement[0], measurement[0] + measurement[1] * 2)
        logger.info('Result: %s', processed_item)

        # Add the result to the queue of the processed items
        queue_out.put(processed_item)

        # Add some sleep time to avoid a deadlock
        if (i % 5) == 4:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        i += 1

    logger.info('End processing')


def stop_acquisition_and_process(queue_out, event, filepath, max_seconds, max_items):
    """Stop the acquisition and processing loops & store the list in a file"""
    logger = logging.getLogger('stop_acquisition_and_process')

    start_time = time.time()
    output_list = []
    while len(output_list) < max_items and (time.time() - start_time) < max_seconds:
        # wait for the queue to have something
        if queue_out.empty():
            continue

        # Get a processed item from the queue
        processed_item = queue_out.get()
        logger.info('Processed item to save: %s', processed_item)

        # Append the result to the list of the processed items to be saved
        output_list.append(processed_item)

        # Add some sleep time to avoid a deadlock
        if (len(output_list) % 5) == 0:
            time.sleep(0.1)

    # Send the termination event
    logger.info('Setting the termination event...')
    event.set()

    # Save the file with the processed items (one per row)
    with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(['\t'.join(list(map(str, a))) + '\n' for a in output_list])

    return output_list


def run_job():
    """Main program"""
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(name)s - %(asctime)s: %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
    logger = logging.getLogger('run_job')

    # filepath of the file with the list
    fp = 'saved_list.txt'

    # number of processed items to be saved in the file. Only the first num_its will be saved, all the others
    # will be discarded
    num_its = 10

    # maximum time to collect max_its items; when this time expires, the collected items so far will be saved
    max_secs = 5

    # Queue for the measurements
    measure_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=num_its)
    # Queue for the results of the processing
    result_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=num_its)

    # The following event is used to stop the acquisition and the processing when the required number of items has been
    # collected or the maximum allowed time has expired
    ev = threading.Event()

    # Use a ThreadPoolExecutor to manage the threads
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        # create all the threads here
        executor.submit(get_measurements, measure_queue, ev)
        executor.submit(process_measurements, measure_queue, result_queue, ev, max_secs)
        f3 = executor.submit(stop_acquisition_and_process, result_queue, ev, fp, max_secs, num_its)

        # Get the list of processed items also as a result
        res = f3.result()

    # print the number of elements in the list
    logger.info("The processed data has been saved in %s and it contains %s rows", fp, len(res))
```

The function `get_measurements` pretends to collect some measurements, while the function `process_measurements` processes them. The two functions share a queue called `measure_queue`: the `get_measurements` *produces* the values for this queue and feeds it, while the `process_measurements` *consumes* values from this queue and writes the results on a second queue, called `result_queue`. Both functions operate on the queue until an event is verified.
A third function, `stop_acquisition_and_process` handles the saving of the processed measurements, saving them on a file, and stops the threads of the acquisition and of the processing, setting an event. Values to be written are read from the `result_queue` and appended to the result list. As soon as enough processed items have been collected or the allowed time for the computation has expired, the function set the termination event and save the processed items on a file.

The output of the `run_job` will be like this:

```sh
get_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,668: Received measurement: (0, 70)
get_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,668: Received measurement: (1, 37)
get_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,668: Received measurement: (2, 19)
get_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,668: Received measurement: (3, 34)
get_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,668: Received measurement: (4, 23)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,668: Process measurement: (0, 70)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,668: Result: (0, 140)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,668: Process measurement: (1, 37)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,668: Result: (1, 75)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,669: Process measurement: (2, 19)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,669: Result: (2, 40)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,669: Process measurement: (3, 34)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,669: Result: (3, 71)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,669: Process measurement: (4, 23)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,669: Result: (4, 50)
stop_acquisition_and_process - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,669: Processed item to save: (0, 140)
stop_acquisition_and_process - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,669: Processed item to save: (1, 75)
stop_acquisition_and_process - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,669: Processed item to save: (2, 40)
stop_acquisition_and_process - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,669: Processed item to save: (3, 71)
stop_acquisition_and_process - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,669: Processed item to save: (4, 50)
get_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,772: Received measurement: (5, 18)
get_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,773: Received measurement: (6, 20)
get_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,773: Received measurement: (7, 85)
get_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,773: Received measurement: (8, 12)
get_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,773: Received measurement: (9, 76)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,774: Process measurement: (5, 18)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,774: Result: (5, 41)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,775: Process measurement: (6, 20)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,775: Result: (6, 46)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,775: Process measurement: (7, 85)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,775: Result: (7, 177)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,775: Process measurement: (8, 12)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,775: Result: (8, 32)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,775: Process measurement: (9, 76)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,775: Result: (9, 161)
stop_acquisition_and_process - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,775: Processed item to save: (5, 41)
stop_acquisition_and_process - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,775: Processed item to save: (6, 46)
stop_acquisition_and_process - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,776: Processed item to save: (7, 177)
stop_acquisition_and_process - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,776: Processed item to save: (8, 32)
stop_acquisition_and_process - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,776: Processed item to save: (9, 161)
get_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,875: Received measurement: (10, 2)
get_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,875: Received measurement: (11, 51)
get_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,875: Received measurement: (12, 23)
get_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,876: Received measurement: (13, 87)
get_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,876: Received measurement: (14, 14)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,879: Process measurement: (10, 2)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,879: Result: (10, 14)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,879: Process measurement: (11, 51)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,879: Result: (11, 113)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,879: Process measurement: (12, 23)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,879: Result: (12, 58)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,880: Process measurement: (13, 87)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,880: Result: (13, 187)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,880: Process measurement: (14, 14)
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,880: Result: (14, 42)
stop_acquisition_and_process - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,880: Setting the termination event...
get_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,978: End of acquisition
process_measurements - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,983: End processing
run_job - 2022-01-22 01:14:56,984: The processed data has been saved in saved_list.txt and it contains 10 rows
```

The output can help you in following the interactions between the different threads and the data flow. As you can see, the order of arrival of the measurement is preserved and no measurement is lost (and this is another pros of using a queue to communicate between different threads).

You can find a good introduction to the producer/consumer implementation in Python using threads [here](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/#producer-consumer-threading) (the example in this answer is based on that page).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use threads to do that:

```
from threading import Thread;
import time

start_measure_flag = True


#Your pretty function declared here
def start_measure():
    global start_measure_flag
    while start_measure_flag:
        print("Hello, world!")
        # Read the counter&  store in list

#The function that stop the function up here
def stop_measure():
    global start_measure_flag
    start_measure_flag = False
    # stop while loop & store the list in file

# A thread to start the "start_measure" in parallel
thr1 = Thread(target=start_measure)

# Start the thread
thr1.start()

# Sleep the main thread for 3 seconds
time.sleep(3)

# Call your function that stop the "start_measure"
stop_measure()

# Done :)
print("Done!")
```

It's simple in python, and give you the paralellism.

Comment: Not all CPUs have 2 threads per core.  Some have 1, some have more than 2.  However, that's completely irrelevant to the question.  CPU hyperthreads are not related to operating system threads in any way.

Comment: @tim CPU's don't have threads at all, ever. Threads are purely a theoretical concept, an abstraction that can be mapped onto virtually any hardware. You don't need hardware-level parallelism to implement multithreading (as evidenced by Windows 9x). It's wildly unclear what point you were trying to make.

Comment: @IInspectable -- Wrong.  As you can see from my comment, I was talking about hyperthreads, which are very much a physical concept.  The original answer specifically mentioned hyperthreads.  It  was edited to remove that line after my comment.

Comment: @tim Hyper-threading is an **implementation detail**. It allows a CPU core to appear as individual logical cores that can execute instructions on independent data in parallel. With that an OS can schedule threads simultaneously; the CPU still doesn't know what a thread is. It is strictly the OS that manages the CPU cores' architectural state, thereby giving the impression of running multiple threads of execution. An OS could also decide (with the help of a specially designed compiler) to run a single thread across multiple cores.

Comment: @tim If you *"KNOW"* all of this, why do you insist on making a point that is unfounded? That doesn't look like a sustainable strategy.

Comment: I am not making unfounded points at all.  The ORIGINAL answer asserted that there were 2 threads per core (meaning "hyperthreads").  I pointed out that was false, and in any case was irrelevant to the question.  All of that is absolutely true.  I don't know what you are trying to read into that, but it's not there.

Answer (score -2):

it may be informative, please look at

```
import asyncio
import os
import random


start_measure_flag = True

async def randsleep(caller=None) -> None:
    i = random.randint(0, 10)
    if caller:
        print(f"{caller} sleeping for {i} seconds.")
    await asyncio.sleep(i)


async def makeitem(size: int = 5) -> str:
    return os.urandom(size).hex()


async def start_measure():
    global start_measure_flag
    while start_measure_flag:
        await randsleep(caller=f"start_measure")
        i = await makeitem()
        print(f"created {i}")


async def stop_measure():
    global start_measure_flag
    for n in range(3):
        await randsleep(caller=f"stop_measure")
        print(f"stop {n}")
    start_measure_flag = False



async def run_workload():
    global start_measure_flag
    while start_measure_flag:
        await randsleep(caller=f"run_workload")
        print(f"run_workload-done")


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(start_measure(),run_workload(),stop_measure())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: While I personally didn't give a down vote, I would surmise the rationale is based on the following: 1) You say your response maybe informative with out elaborating on how or why.  2) You provide no informative data to guide the OP or any other reader with respect to how this response answers he question.

Comment: I did down-vote. Code-only answers are useless. Without rationale, there's no value at all.

Comment: Can explaining the code give more information than the code itself?

Comment: Of course! Source code can tell you *"what"* is being done, but it cannot answer the *"why?"*.